# PyQt5 GUI freezes when plugging in a USB sound card and operating the GUI at the same time

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I have a strange behaviour on my PyQt5 GUI running on my raspberry Pi. Every time I plug in a USB device to my Raspberry and operate one of the labels, sliders, etc. my GUI seems to freeze.

The GUI does not freeze completely, but I cant switch pages and some pushbuttons do not work. Can anybody explain to me, why this happens or if there is any known solution for this problem?

I came across [another thread](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nbEQH-WAxzT62wt9l9sY3__jAdwDgy4N/view?usp=sharing)with similar issues which has to do with external processes. Do I have the same problem?

Additional to the comment from musicamante:
The USB device is a PCM2900 audio card. The program is a GUI, containing different sliders and a button to open/close a horizontal burger menu. If I plug/unplug the audio card while one of the sliders or the button is pressed, the touch functionality just freezes. This only happen while having physical access on the GUI. If I operate the GUI on my raspberry over VNC, everything works without problems. If i have a freezing GUI and then open the GUI over VNC, I am also able to operate the GUI over VNC but even if it works again over VNC, I am still unable to operate the GUI over physical touch input.

Someone might think that the problem isn't the pyqt5 GUI:
If i just close the freezing GUI, the Raspbian desktop shows up which can be operated over physical touch input without issues.

Update based on the newest comments:
I created a simple user interface which just shows a slider. I wrote a script to plug/unplug my USB sound card every 10 seconds. The result is the same and my slider still gets freezed when touching and plugging in the usb device at the same time.

The Program is started automatically at startup via a .SH file and I also disable the visibility of the mouse cursor. I set up the visibility in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf an added the line "xserver-command = X -nocursor". However the issues are still present if i start the script manually over VNC or when I enable the visibility of the mouse cursor.

Maybe interesting to mention is, that the issues only occur when i plug in the usb device. When unplugging while touching/moving the slider has no impact. Furthermore, if I plug in the usb device the slider gets not stuck instantly but like 2-3 seconds delayed. Maybe because the system needs its time to properly set up everthing, I dont know...

When I plug in a usb mouse, I am still able to move the stucked slider. But even after "unstuck" the slider with my physical mouse, I am still unable to move the slider again over the touchscreen.

The code I used is following:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import threading


class Ui_slider(object):
    def setupUi(self, welcomescreen):
        if not welcomescreen.objectName():
            welcomescreen.setObjectName(u"welcomescreen")
        welcomescreen.resize(480, 800)
        welcomescreen.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(welcomescreen)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.Background = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Background.setObjectName(u"Background")
        self.Background.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 480, 800))
        self.Background.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Background.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Slider = QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.Slider.setObjectName(u"Slider")
        self.Slider.setGeometry(QRect(180, 120, 108, 520))
        self.Slider.setStyleSheet(u".QSlider {\n"
"    background: transparent;\n"
"       border-radius: 52px;\n"
"       margin: 4px 3px 4px 0px;\n"
"       border: 2px solid black; /* Rahmenfarbe */\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
".QSlider::groove:vertical {\n"
"    border: 0px solid #262626;\n"
"    width: 0px;\n"
"    background: #393939;\n"
"    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;\n"
"       \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
".QSlider::handle:vertical {\n"
"    background: rgb(0,0,0);\n"
"    border: 4px solid rgb(255,255,255);\n"
"       border-radius: 50px;\n"
"    height: 92px;\n"
"    margin: 0px -50px 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::add-page:vertical {\n"
"background: rgb(255,255,255);\n"
"margin: -51px -50px 0px -50px;\n"
"border-radius: 50px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::handle:vertical:pressed {\n"
"background-color: rgb(127,127,127);\n"
"}")
        self.Slider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.Slider.setPageStep(0)
        self.Slider.setValue(1000)
        self.Slider.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        welcomescreen.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(welcomescreen)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(welcomescreen)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, welcomescreen):
        welcomescreen.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("welcomescreen", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.Background.setText("")
    # retranslateUi



class sliderscreen(QMainWindow):                                                                        #Build Window#
    def __init__(self):                                                                                 #            #
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)                                                                      #            #
        self.ui = Ui_slider()                                                                           #            #     
        self.ui.setupUi(self)                                                                           #            #
        self.show()                                                                                     #            #
        self.ui.Slider.setValue(500)                                                                    #Build Window#                                                                                                  



if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Backlight.Backlight(0)
    #Expander.initIO()                                                                                           
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = sliderscreen()                                                                                                

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I also created an strace with timestamps. I plugged in the usb audio driver at 03:06:18 and roughly 2-3 seconds later, the GUI got stuck. Because of the file length, you can take a look to the file under following  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nbEQH-WAxzT62wt9l9sY3__jAdwDgy4N/view?usp=sharing)  or just have a look at following snippet:

```
03:06:21.214980 writev(5, [{iov_base=";\3\5\0\21\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\264\0x\0l\0\10\2\202\3\n\0\6\0\300\1\21\0\300\1"..., iov_len=76}], 1) = 76
03:06:21.215866 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=663580458}) = 0
03:06:21.216046 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.222560 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.222793 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.223095 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.223307 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=670998767}) = 0
03:06:21.223459 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.223629 read(7, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.223813 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
03:06:21.223985 writev(5, [{iov_base="+\0\1\0", iov_len=4}], 1) = 4
03:06:21.224236 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
03:06:21.224393 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.226066 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
03:06:21.226286 writev(5, [{iov_base=";\3\5\0\21\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\264\0x\0l\0\10\2\202\3\n\0\6\0\300\1\21\0\300\1"..., iov_len=76}], 1) = 76
03:06:21.227191 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=674912059}) = 0
03:06:21.227385 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.230882 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.231096 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.231394 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.231604 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=679294345}) = 0
03:06:21.231755 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.231924 read(7, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.232104 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
03:06:21.232275 writev(5, [{iov_base="+\0\1\0", iov_len=4}], 1) = 4
03:06:21.232611 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
03:06:21.232775 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.234468 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
03:06:21.234696 writev(5, [{iov_base=";\3\5\0\21\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\264\0x\0l\0\10\2\202\3\n\0\6\0\300\1\21\0\300\1"..., iov_len=76}], 1) = 76
03:06:21.235475 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=683185229}) = 0
03:06:21.235659 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.243113 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.243360 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.243695 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=691396733}) = 0
03:06:21.243861 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.244031 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.244188 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=691875654}) = 0
03:06:21.244332 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.254166 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.254407 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.254738 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=702441244}) = 0
03:06:21.254906 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.255080 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.255240 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=702929146}) = 0
03:06:21.255389 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.263794 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.264080 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.266964 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=714724297}) = 0
03:06:21.268051 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.268265 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.268454 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=716150745}) = 0
03:06:21.268615 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.413686 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.413951 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
03:06:21.414138 writev(5, [{iov_base="\2030\2\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=8}], 1) = 8
03:06:21.414330 futex(0xbef540d0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
03:06:21.420667 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.420824 futex(0xbef540d4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
03:06:21.421250 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.421631 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.422164 futex(0x16b1bd4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
03:06:21.422580 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.423046 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=870744806}) = 0
03:06:21.423211 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.423386 read(7, "\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.423547 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=871234505}) = 0
03:06:21.423691 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.426248 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.426452 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.426625 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=874314194}) = 0
03:06:21.426773 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.426938 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.427092 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=874779226}) = 0
03:06:21.427235 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.434555 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.434792 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.434972 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=882666622}) = 0
03:06:21.435122 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.435285 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.435438 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=883127488}) = 0
03:06:21.435578 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.446079 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.446310 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.446487 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=894179591}) = 0
03:06:21.446635 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.446797 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.446949 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=894638068}) = 0
03:06:21.447089 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.457713 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.457956 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.458137 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=905831188}) = 0
03:06:21.458286 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.458449 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.458601 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=906292443}) = 0
03:06:21.458743 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.469265 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.469492 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.469671 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=917362990}) = 0
03:06:21.469818 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.469980 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.470132 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=917820745}) = 0
03:06:21.470300 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.477575 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.477810 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.477986 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=925679345}) = 0
03:06:21.478134 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.478297 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.478446 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=926132526}) = 0
03:06:21.478583 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.488989 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.489178 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.489342 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=937030705}) = 0
03:06:21.489483 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.489642 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.489788 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=937474219}) = 0
03:06:21.489924 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.500640 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.500862 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.501032 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=948722950}) = 0
03:06:21.501176 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.501334 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.501481 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=949168371}) = 0
03:06:21.501617 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.512230 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.512502 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.512680 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=960369565}) = 0
03:06:21.512824 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.512985 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.513132 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=960819079}) = 0
03:06:21.513269 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.520457 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.520652 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.520816 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=968504385}) = 0
03:06:21.520957 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.521115 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.521261 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=968947195}) = 0
03:06:21.521397 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.531941 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.532126 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.532294 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=979986077}) = 0
03:06:21.532511 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.532725 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.532911 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=980604237}) = 0
03:06:21.533060 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.543667 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.543887 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.544057 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=991746450}) = 0
03:06:21.544199 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.544358 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.544506 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=609, tv_nsec=992192260}) = 0
03:06:21.544642 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.555226 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.555457 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.555631 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=3320326}) = 0
03:06:21.555803 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.555962 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.556110 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=3796488}) = 0
03:06:21.556247 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.563475 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.563697 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.563866 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=11554812}) = 0
03:06:21.564008 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.564166 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.564317 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=12007214}) = 0
03:06:21.564463 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.586559 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.586778 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.586950 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=34641341}) = 0
03:06:21.587097 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.587255 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.587403 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=35090540}) = 0
03:06:21.587540 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.609604 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.609818 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.609990 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=57679353}) = 0
03:06:21.610134 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.610291 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.610439 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=58125385}) = 0
03:06:21.610575 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.617862 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.618076 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.618246 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=65937301}) = 0
03:06:21.618391 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.618550 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.618698 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=66383945}) = 0
03:06:21.618833 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.629482 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.629721 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.629915 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=77608287}) = 0
03:06:21.630071 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.630238 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.630397 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=78088837}) = 0
03:06:21.630546 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.641076 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.641315 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.641510 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=89205533}) = 0
03:06:21.641670 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.641836 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.641997 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=89687213}) = 0
03:06:21.642143 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.652660 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.653541 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.653724 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=101413050}) = 0
03:06:21.653868 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.654034 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.654196 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=101892952}) = 0
03:06:21.654353 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.661050 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.661279 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.661473 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=109169615}) = 0
03:06:21.661631 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.661797 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.661958 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=109649498}) = 0
03:06:21.662101 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.672576 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.672797 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.672970 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=120659306}) = 0
03:06:21.673113 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.673270 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.673417 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=121103727}) = 0
03:06:21.673553 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.684095 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.684308 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.684476 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=132165256}) = 0
03:06:21.684620 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.684776 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.684922 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=132608326}) = 0
03:06:21.685058 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.695650 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.695861 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.696030 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=143718706}) = 0
03:06:21.696174 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.696331 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.696477 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=144163387}) = 0
03:06:21.696613 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.703850 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.704043 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.704208 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=151896044}) = 0
03:06:21.704348 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.704504 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.704652 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=152338225}) = 0
03:06:21.704787 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.715716 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.715930 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.716101 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=163789583}) = 0
03:06:21.716242 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.716401 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.716547 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=164233949}) = 0
03:06:21.716684 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.727039 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.727248 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.727415 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=175103925}) = 0
03:06:21.727557 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.727714 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.727861 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=175547716}) = 0
03:06:21.727997 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.738571 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.738778 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.738944 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=186633153}) = 0
03:06:21.739086 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.739273 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.739421 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=187108592}) = 0
03:06:21.739558 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.746769 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.746958 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.747122 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=194810991}) = 0
03:06:21.747263 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.747420 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.747568 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=195255319}) = 0
03:06:21.747705 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.758480 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.758708 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.758881 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=206572809}) = 0
03:06:21.759038 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.759214 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.759374 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=207061377}) = 0
03:06:21.759512 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.769986 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.770204 write(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
03:06:21.770374 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=218063333}) = 0
03:06:21.770515 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.770674 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
03:06:21.770822 clock_gettime64(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=610, tv_nsec=218511643}) = 0
03:06:21.770962 poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
03:06:21.902476 read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
```